# How to create pandas output for custom transformers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

There are a lot of changes in scikit-learn 1.2.0 where it supports pandas output for all of the transformers but how can I use it in a custom transformer?

**In [1]:** Here is my custom transformer which is a standard scaler:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class StandardScalerCustom(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)
        self.std = np.std(X, axis=0)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return (X - self.mean) / self.std
```

**In [2]:** Created a specific `scale` pipeline

```
scale_pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScalerCustom())
```

**In [3]:** Added in a full pipeline where it may get mixed with scalers, imputers, encoders etc.

```
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("imputer", impute_pipe, ['column_1'])
    ("scaler", scale_pipe, ['column_2'])
])

# From documentation
full_pipeline.set_output(transform="pandas")
```

Got this error:

**ValueError**: Unable to configure output for StandardScalerCustom() because `set_output` is not available.

---

There is a solution and it can be:
`set_config(transform_output="pandas")`

But in **case-to-case basis**, how can I create a function in StandardScalerCustom() class that can fix the error above?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that one the rationales behind the enhancement of [`set_config()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.set_config.html#sklearn.set_config) by means of the parameter `transform_output` was indeed to enable also *custom transformers* to output pandas DataFrames.

By looking at the [underlying code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2e481f114169396660f0051eee1bcf6bcddfd556/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py#L150), I've found one hack that allows *custom transformers* to output pandas DataFrames without the need to ***explicitly*** set the global configuration; it is sufficient to implement a dummy `.get_feature_names_out()` method. However, this works just because in this way the global configuration is *automatically* set.
Indeed, [`_auto_wrap_is_configured()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2e481f114169396660f0051eee1bcf6bcddfd556/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py#L157) returns *True* if `.get_feature_names_out()` is available and, if so, `full_pipeline` reverts to calling [this `.set_output()`
method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2e481f114169396660f0051eee1bcf6bcddfd556/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py#L200) rather than getting to [this `._safe_set_output()` method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/98cf537f5c538fdbc9d27b851cf03ce7611b8a48/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py#L237), where the first sets the global configuration with `transform="pandas"` automatically, while the second would output the [ValueError](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2e481f114169396660f0051eee1bcf6bcddfd556/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py#L264) that you're getting.

Here's a working example:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': [np.nan, 1.34, 10.98, 3.34, 5.32], 'column_2': [9.78, 20.34, 43.54, 1.98, 7.85]})

class StandardScalerCustom(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)
        self.std = np.std(X, axis=0)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return (X - self.mean) / self.std

    def get_feature_names_out(self):
        pass

impute_pipe = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer())
scale_pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScalerCustom())

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("imputer", impute_pipe, ['column_1']),
    ("scaler", scale_pipe, ['column_2'])
])

full_pipeline.set_output(transform="pandas")
full_pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

In most case custom methods 'transform' return numpy arrays. To convert them back to pandas DataFrame you need to extract columns while fitting. After that you need to add method get_feature_names_out, which returns column names. Try to use this code:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class StandardScalerCustom(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.columns_ = X.columns
        self.mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)
        self.std = np.std(X, axis=0)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return (X - self.mean) / self.std
    
    def get_feature_names_out(self, *args, **params):
        return self.columns_
```